# How to use the word total properly?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Hey guys which one of the following sentence makes sense the most?

• The numbers were great and totalled 95%

• The numbers were great and totalled to 95%

• The numbers were great and totalled up to 95%

• The numbers were great and had a total of 95%

• The numbers were great with a total of 95%

Comment: There was total chaos on the interstate yesterday when several cars were totaled.  It was totally awesome!

Comment: All sound fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about: **The numbers were great and summed up to 98%**

**Edit:**

If you want to use the word *total*:

**The numbers were great and totalled up to 98%**

*or*

**The numbers were great and had a total of 98%**

Comment: How can I use summed up to using the word total though?

Comment: Summed up and totalled up mean the same

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: **Why** do these work and the others do not?

Comment: I never said that the others don't work.